# Mysql Query Optimization and Sorting

Tags: mysql

I am confused to asking the question. If any queries then please let me know. I don't know how to ask it.

I have above 90000 of hotel lists in MYSQL database. If I search hotels for a particular city normally it getting out the lists from 90000 results. I want to sort the the hotels against the particular cities. For this reason normally I use the filtering query, but now I have noticed that it is taking much time to pull out the results from 90000 list. I think it would be better if I search hotels within new york city it will return 56 hotels from 90000 lists and after that filtering such as price, rating etc will search from just only from 56 lists. Is there any way in MYSQL to pull out the hotels. It may be called virtual table or view i don't know. Please help me to solve.

Comment: Is your hotels table indexed on city?

Comment: Having a list of your table structure and indexes would be a very good start.  Creating a "View" might not be your best answer, and combining a query by location and pricing is nothing for mysql to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may very well do all the filtering and sorting in one query but you need to add indexes to your base.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

90 000 rows : that's a small table. It's usual to deal with ten times more and have results in 10ms.

Comment: +1. 90K rows is a tiny table indeed, and partitioning it looks like overkill. )

Comment: It will be bigger. I am work on it and it will goes to near about 10,00,000 hotels

Comment: Assuming you mean 1M or 10M, using indexes is still the way to go. Add indexes on all columns appearing in where or sort by clauses and it will be fine. Today's bases are BIG.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may always use a view, like that:

```
CREATE VIEW ny_hotels AS
SELECT price, range, etc FROM hotels WHERE city = 'NY'
```

... then query this view like a normal table:

```
SELECT price, rating FROM ny_hotels WHERE hotel_id = @some_hotel_id
```

But may I suggest indexing the `city` column in the main table instead?